# Atomic compare_exchange, but based on flag being set, rather than equality?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

std::atomic provides compare_exchange_strong(a,b) tests if the underlying value is currently "a", and if so, then replaces it with "b", in an atomic/thread-safe way.

Is there any lock-free, atomic way to perform a similar operation, but instead of testing for equality with "b", it would treat "b" as a flag, and perform the replacement if the underlying value has that flag set?

So in principle, something like

```
bool compare_exchange_flags(std::atomic<int>& underlying, int& flag, int replacement)
{
  auto tmp = underlying.load();

  if((tmp & flag) == flag) // only perform replacement if flag is set
  {
    flag = tmp; // emulate compare_exchange_strong, where expected value is replaced with actual value
    underlying = replacement;
    return true;
  } else {
    flag = underlying.load();
    return false;
  }
}
```

only in a version that would.. well, actually work ;) (above operations are not at all atomic of course)

Thanks!

---

For context: This is for a message bus. This bus has memory regions associated with some states (such as READABLE, WRITEABLE).

Each state needs to be enhanceable with some flags - for example, a state could just be "WRITEABLE", meaning a writer can freely write data to the fragment (readers are currently spinning / busy polling).
Or it could be "WRITEABLE | SIGNALED", which would imply a writer can acquire this memory for writing, but needs to trigger an event once data is written to notify the readers.

So (VERY conceptually, this isn't actual code - just to roughly demonstrate) something like

```
void send(...)
{
  auto expected = WRITEABLE;
  if(compare_exchange_flags(status, expected, WRITE_RESERVED))
  {
    // ... write data ...

    status = WRITTEN;

    if((expected & SIGNALED) = SIGNALED)
      wakeUpReaders();
  } else {
    tryAnotherRegion();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not such instruction. But this kind of operations are usually performed with a loop that try to exchange the value while the value has the flag:

```
bool replace_if_flag(std::atomic<int>& underlying, int flag, int replacement){

  auto tmp = underlying.load();

  if(!(tmp & flag)) return false;

  while (!underlying.compare_exchange_weak(tmp,replacement)){
    if(!(tmp & flag)) return false;
    }

  return true;
  }
```